# Cheesy convestibles

Tags: etymology, orthography

Having been schooled in all things British largely by the Pythons, I've been using this word in my speech for years (it comes from the Cheese Shop sketch), but had never actually written it till today. When I did, I found to my surprise that it doesn't appear to be an actual English word! So... am I just mis-typing it so badly (having mis-heard what Cleese is saying) that no spell-checker or Google is able to recognize what I'm trying to say, or did JC & Co. conjure this up entirely out of nothing? And if so, how long does it take (it's been >30 years!) for a word that so many people know the meaning of to officially enter the lexicon?

Comment: General reference. Python scripts are easily consulted online.

Comment: Hmmmm... This question is not much of a cheese shop, is it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's cheesy comestibles.

Comestible is defined as: any substance that can be used as food; edible: suitable for use as food